# Linear Mixed Model with Date Covariate and Missing Values

Tags: mixed-model, time-varying-covariate, crossed-random-effects

Let us consider the table below, which contains (a sample of) the sale prices of different properties in successive years (not all properties are sold each year):

```
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|             | 2000   | 2001   | 2002   | 2003   | 2004   | 2005   | 2006   | 2007   |
|-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
| property 1  | 202000 | 214000 |        |        | 241000 | 252000 | 262000 |        |
| property 2  |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
| property 3  |        | 378000 |        |        | 413000 | 420000 |        | 440000 |
| property 4  |        |        | 223000 |        |        |        | 251000 | 260000 |
| property 5  |        |        |        | 206000 | 220000 |        | 234000 |        |
| property 6  |        |        |        | 312000 |        |        |        |        |
| property 7  | 120000 |        | 143000 | 154000 |        | 180000 | 186000 | 198000 |
| property 8  |        | 211000 |        |        |        |        |        | 270000 |
| property 9  | 221000 |        | 241000 |        |        |        |        |        |
| property 10 | 314000 | 326000 | 333000 | 344000 | 352000 | 362000 |        |        |
+-------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

A number of characteristics, not shown here (number of bedrooms, etc.) is known for each property. The objective is to build a statistical model to predict the value of a given property, on the basis of its characteristics and the year considered.

One possibility would be to fit a linear mixed model with partially crossed random effects, e.g.:

```
model <- lmer(price ~ bedrooms + (1|property) + (1|date), data=prices)
```

but this would ignore the (generally increasing, non-linear) relationship between date and price. Could the model be adapted to take this relationship into account? If not, would another model be better suited for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitting random intercepts for `date` does not really make sense here. You want to accout for the positive association with time (`date`). I would suggest a model such as:

```
model <- lmer(price ~ date + bedrooms + (1|property) , data=prices)
```

This allows for a linear slope with respect to time. To allow for a nonlinear association, you could introduce higher order terms soch as `date^2` and/or splines, or transform the variable in some way (eg `log`). You should be guided by the underlying theory and perhaps some visualisation of the date to determine the best nonlinear form.

You might also want to allow for autocorrelation, in which case you could look at a different package that supports an AR(1) or other structure, such as the glmmTMB package in R.

Another consideration would be to centre the time variable, which often makes sense for interpretability, particularly if you also decide to fit random slopes for `date` and/or involve `date` in an interaction with `bedrooms`